# research into using parasites medically

Tags: research, parasites

Can humans utilise parasites medically to control diet?

Parasites are dangerous and to be avoided, especially the tapeworm.

[healthline.com/health/diet-and-weight-loss/tapeworm-diet](https://healthline.com/health/diet-and-weight-loss/tapeworm-diet)

[medicinenet.com/eating_tapeworms_for_weight_loss/views.htm](https://medicinenet.com/eating_tapeworms_for_weight_loss/views.htm)

---

However could the correct species of a parasite such as a genetically different parasitic worm be bred or genetically modified for this use?

---

The parasite may need to reliably:

1. Be cleaned before use.
2. Have its reproductive organs removed.
3. Have its growth limited.
4. Attach itself to the correct part of the digestive tract.
5. Eat a predicable amount of specific substances, for example excess calories and food that cases an allergy early in digestion, and everything remaining towards the end of the process.
6. Not be too hard to kill if needed.

Comment: You might want to google tapeworm+diet. It's been around since at least the Victorian era.

Comment: The "tapeworm diet" is amazingly stupid, I know and I hope that it is not excessively defensive to point out that my question shows that I researched that. @Carey_Gregory

Comment: When I wrote my comments above your question showed no research at all, so yes, I think your response was excessively defensive. But thank you for improving your question.

Comment: thanks :) I'll fix that now. I really hope this SE site makes it as it could be extremely useful.